# Are there any JavaScript syntax highlighters with a small footprint and nice formatting?

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting

Ok so I've tried out the seemly most popular syntax highlighter that seems to be out there

http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

but the file size is quite large, it seems a little heavy to include it and the format of the highlighted code I feel looks ugly.

Is there any alternative?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers I had a look at those highlighters,. I like rainbows lightweight ness. But not a fan of the styling. And Google's Prettify is good although double the file size of rainbow. In the end I decided to whip up my own. If anyones interested I put a version up on bitbucket.

https://bitbucket.org/SharkAttack/syntax-highlighter

Answer (score 2):

[Google's Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) is slightly smaller and lighter but a syntax highlighter that runs in JavaScript is inherently large, especially if it has to support many languages. One option is to run something server-side like [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) but that's a little harder to setup depending on what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

[Rainbow](http://craig.is/making/rainbows/)'s light weight and works nicely.

There's a few out there, google's your friend (I'm only able to post two hyperlinks, sorry! Otherwise, I'd post more that I found.)

Here's another link I found:

- http://www.dreamcss.com/2009/07/10-syntax-highlighters-to-enhance-your.html

Hope you find one of them useful.